# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'done'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Well, this is kind of a homework project, and I am sort of stumped. I have tried to do str/int conversions. The original was line was `allScores.append ( int( strScore / 10 )` - But I found the /10 to be redundant, as I wanted to append the value itself. I am debugging a program deliberately full of flaws for simple grade calculations.

```
MAX_SCORE = 10
MIN_SCORE = 0

def GetValidInput ( prompt ):
    strScore = input ( prompt ) # Added () to isdigit
    while ( not strScore.isdigit() and strScore != "done" ) or \
          ( strScore.isdigit() and \
          ( int(strScore) < MIN_SCORE or int(strScore) > MAX_SCORE ) ):     #Added int() as is it was comparing strings and numbers -- Changed AND     to OR
        if ( strScore.isdigit() ):
            print ( "Please enter a number between %0d and %0d." \
                    % ( MIN_SCORE, MAX_SCORE), end=' ' )
        else:
            print ( "Please enter only whole numbers.", end=' ' )
        strScore = input ( prompt )
    return strScore

allScores = [ ]
strScore = GetValidInput ( "Enter HW#" + str(len( allScores )) + "     score: " ) #Added str(), as is printing a string
while ( strScore != "done" ):
    strScore = GetValidInput ( "Enter HW#" + str(len( allScores )) + "     score: " ) # Fixed GetvalidInput to GetValidInput -- Added str() to     allScores to work in string -- Changed line place with the one below
    allScores.append ( int(strScore) ) # Fixed MAXSCORE to MAX_SCORE --     Added int() as it was comparing string strScore to an Integer --     Changed line place with the one above -- Removed 
    print(str(allScores))
```

For some reason, I keep getting
    `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'done'`
, but I definitely need to append the value to the list, and get an average. Is there a way to do this without adding in another IF? Still learning python and basic programming here.

Any helpful advice?

Comment: Your `GetValidInput()` function is guaranteed to return `'done'`. And then you try to cast that to `int()`.

Comment: I need a list of intergers, but I need done to end the loop. What would you suggest? I looked at what you said and removed the int(), but then I seem to run into an issue summing up the numbers in the list later.
Unless I can make this work with it
     pctScore = sum ( allScores ) // ( len ( allScores ) * 100 )

Answer (score 0):

Just leave the `int()` casting for later. Append everything as a string, and then, when you're done with the loop, `pop()` the last element (the `'done'`) and convert the remaining `allScores` to integers (with `map()`, a comprehension, whatever).

```
while strScore != "done":
    strScore = GetValidInput("Enter HW#{}     score: ".format(len(allScores)))
    allScores.append(strScore)
    print(allScores)
allScores.pop()
allScores = list(map(int, allScores))
```

Comment: Thanks, got through the rest of the program just now, and this part of it was accepted by the larger program. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Adrian - Happy to help. If you like, you can mark this answer as having solved the issue by clicking the check mark below its score.